# Output of a function in maxima

Tags: maxima

I have programmed a function F which round the input following some specific rules. For example, if my input is `F(0.1355)` it gives as output `1.4b-1`. The problem is that, when I do `F(0.1355)^2`, it gives me `1.96382999420166b-2`, when it should give me 0.14^2, i.e, `1.96b-2`. Why is this happening? and, how can I fix it?

This is the code of my function:

```
F(x):=(block ([log10,aaa,fpprec],log10(x):=entier(log(x)/log(10)), 
    vnorm(x):= if x/(10^(log10(x)))<2 then 1/(10^(log10(x)-1)) else 1/10^(log10(x)),
     aaa(x):= x*vnorm(x),
    fpprec:if aaa(x)<20 then 2 else 1,bfloat((round(aaa(x)))*1/vnorm(x)))); `
```

More info: I **can't** declare fpprec as global variable. I know that would solve my problem.
Best regards,

Lievet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `F(x)^2` is computed with the value of `fpprec` outside of the `block`, which is 16. First `F(x)` is computed with `fpprec` = 2; call that result `foo`. Then `foo^2` is computed with `fpprec` = 16.

I don't know a way to limit the precision for bigfloat computations to the precision of the operands. It may be possible with simplification rules (`tellsimp` or `tellsimpafter`) but, if so, it is probably not easy.

Two ideas to make some progress here. (1) Consider using rational numbers instead of bigfloats. I.e. return 7/5 instead of 1.4b-1. (2) If you are just trying to limit the digits that are printed, use `fpprintprec`.

Maybe if you say more about what is your larger goal here, someone will have some advice.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have an easy solution. I don't want to have as output rational numbers, so I didn't consider that way. Anyway, as you pointed out, I will use fpprintprec though  only limits the display. Thank you!